# MemberExpression.ToString() - substituting parameters

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

Given this method:

```
public static string GetMemberIdentifier<TProp>(Expression<Func<Team, TProp>> expression)
{
    return expression.Body.ToString();
}
```

A lambda expression can be converted to a string representation:

```
var nameIdentifier1 = GetMemberIdentifier(t => t.Members[1].Name);
```

which gives (a):

```
t.Members.get_Item(1).Name
```

However calling it with:

```
var i = 0;
var nameIdentifier2 = GetMemberIdentifier(t => t.Members[i].Name);
```

results in (b):

```
t.Members.get_Item(value(Program+<>c__DisplayClass2).i).Name
```

Is it possible to get the output in b) to be the same as in a) ?

.NET Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/cHG7H3

**Desired Usage(Simpified):**

```
for(int i = 0; i < team.Members.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(GetMemberIdentifier(t => t.Members[i].Name));
}
```

Output:

```
t.Members.get_Item(0).Name
t.Members.get_Item(1).Name
t.Members.get_Item(2).Name
```

Comment: The lambda is closed over the `i`, it genuinely references it. The output is correct. You can only construct another lambda where the reference to `i` would be replaced with a const derived from the current value of `i`.

Comment: OK if it's correct. but is there a way of manipulating it to get what I want?

Comment: Like I said, you can write a method that inspects the passed `Expression` and constructs another `Expression` from it that has all its dependent subtrees calculated and replaced with constants. But then the output of such method will depend on the current values referenced by the lambda at the moment of calling that method. That is, it will produce different results at different times, on the same lambda.

Comment: That sounds like what I want, any chance of posting an answer to that effect?

Comment: You should define your requirements more strictly, and/or limit what expressions the lambda is allowed to use. E.g. what would be the desired output for `t => t.Members[t.Members[Random.Next(i, i+2)].Value + 42 - i].Name`?

Comment: I've added more information, as above it will just be simple array indexing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your lambdas are going to be this simple, then you can do:

```cs
public class ArgumentsTransformToConstantVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Func<object>> args;

    public ArgumentsTransformToConstantVisitor(params (string varname, Func<object> resolver)[] args)
    {
        this.args = args.ToDictionary(i => i.varname, i => i.resolver);
    }
    
    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        if (node.Expression is ConstantExpression && this.args.TryGetValue(node.Member.Name, out Func<object> resolver))
            return Expression.Constant(resolver());
        
        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }

    public string GetMemberIdentifier<TProp>(Expression<Func<Team, TProp>> expression)
    {
        return ((LambdaExpression)this.Visit(expression)).ToString();
    }
}
```

```cs
int i = 0;

var visitor = new ArgumentsTransformToConstantVisitor(("i", () => i));

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(visitor.GetMemberIdentifier(t => t.Members[i].Name));
}
```